# How to deal with double (or multiple) copy constructors for class with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

There is a class called "X" like this:

```
class X {
private:
    int *ptr;
public:
    X() {
        ptr = new int[2];
        ptr[0] = 0;
        ptr[1] = 0;
    }
    X(int a, int b) {
        ptr = new int[2];
        ptr[0] = a;
        ptr[1] = b;
    }
    X(const X &val) {
        delete[] ptr;
        ptr = new int[2];
        ptr[0] = val.ptr[0];
        ptr[1] = val.ptr[1];
    }
    X get() {
        X ret(ptr[0], ptr[1]);
        return ret;
    }
};
```

Suppose that there are variable X that is defined with `X v(2, 3)`.

If we call `v.get()`, it's okay.

But, if we call `v.get().get()`, it's not okay. It produces runtime error in `delete[] ptr` section in copy constructor, which the content is that I am trying to delete the undefined (0xcccccccc) pointer.

One possible option for dealing with this is, that using C++-STL like `<array>` or `<vector>`. But I want to implement with pointer.

How to deal with this runtime error, with pointer-based implementation?

Comment: The error is that you try to delete `ptr` in the copy constructor. `ptr` is not assigned yet so you actually try to delete a random pointer. Just remove that line. It is not needed

Comment: Why are you deleting `ptr` on a copy constructor?

Comment: @IanA.B.King I'm implementating class using array which the size is more than 100k. It was bugged so I looked into bug - and the very very simplified version of the bug is class X. Deleting is for memory saving.

Comment: But you're not saving memory. Which memory would you save anyway?

Comment: But there is no memory to delete (yet). It is not allocated until the next line.

Comment: You should not delete data on a copy constructor, as a general rule.

Comment: Also, I highly recommend using a dynamically allocated std::array or a plain std::vector.

Comment: As @IanA.B.King and @Thoma-Sparber said you shouldn't delete unitialized pointer inside constructor. It causes errors because `ptr` shows garbage and delete operation doesn't recognize given memory address as valid memory allocation. To fix this 1. Remove `delete[] ptr` or assign `X(const X &val) : ptr(NULL) {...}` because delete operation on NULL pointer doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Second thing is that call `v.get().get()` shouldn't produce any error because int this call you are using twice constructor `X(int a, int b)` not `X(const X &val)`. To produce error you should do something like that `X v1(2,3); X v2(v1);`.

Comment: Constructors are what creates objects. Until the constructor is run, the object isn't in existence yet. That's true for copy constructors too. So if the object doesn't exist yet, how can it have a `ptr` already allocated?

Comment: Also you forgot to write a destructor, so with every call to constructor you have a memory leak.

Comment: Aside: the body of your `get` is an overly complex `return *this;`

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you shouldn't `delete[] ptr` in the copy constructor, because it is uninitialised. You don't need to `delete[] ptr` in assignment, either. The **only** place `delete` or `delete[]` should occur is in a destructor.

Tidying up your class, without changing from owning raw pointers

```
class X {
private:
    int *ptr;
public:
    X() : X(0, 0) { }
    X(int a, int b) : ptr(new int[2]) {
        ptr[0] = a;
        ptr[1] = b;
    }
    X(const X &val) : X(val.ptr[0], val.ptr[1]) { }
    X& operator=(const X &val)
    {
        ptr[0] = val.ptr[0];
        ptr[1] = val.ptr[1];
        return *this;
    }
    X(X&& val) : ptr(val.ptr) {
        val.ptr = nullptr;
    }
    X& operator=(X&& val) {
        std::swap(ptr, val.ptr);
        return *this;
    }        
    ~X() { delete[] ptr; }

    X get() {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

As a point of nomenclature, a constructor is only a "[copy constructor](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#1)" if it takes an instance of the class as it's single (non-default) parameter. `X::X(int, int)` is just a constructor. That means there are at most 4 copy constructors (otherwise they would be ambiguous under overload resolution)

```
X::X(X &)
X::X(const X &)
X::X(volatile X &)
X::X(const volatile X &)
```

However defining more than one is a terrible idea, unless you in an obfuscation contest

Comment: Here's a thought - is that `swap` well-defined given that `ptr` has an indeterminate value?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit good point. I think the swap is ok, but the (probably immediate) end of life of `val` would be UB

Comment: (To inevitable third-party commenter: no, I don't mean read from `*ptr`)

Comment: Indeed, I'm used to it being fine with a default-initialised `unique_ptr`

Comment: Yep- to be honest I would probably initialise this `ptr` to zero in all ctors that don't give it some other value. I recognise that some people don't like the "additional work" this entails

Comment: You can't mix delegating constructors and member initialisers

Comment: Well, sure, obviously not those either. I was basically just suggesting `X(X&& val) : ptr(nullptr) { std::swap(ptr, val.ptr); }` (and then applying the same logic as a general rule in life for other constructors) but your edit is better

Comment: there was a swallowed by the edit timer version that did exactly that